# Make a function with nested for loop to get all overlaps between DNA sequences , bioinformatic

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, nested-loops

I have written function `get_overlap` to evaluate the overlap between all
pairs of reads in both left-right and right-left orientations. And now I have to use this function to write a function `get_all_overlaps`, that must return:

A dictionary of dictionaries, specifying the number of overlapping bases for a pair
of reads in a specific left-right orientation. Computing the overlap of a read to
itself is meaningless and must not be included. Assuming the resulting dictionary
of dictionaries is called d, then d['Read2'] will be a dictionary where keys are the
names of reads that have an overlap with read 'Read2' when 'Read2' is put in the
left position, and the values for these keys are the number of overlapping bases for
those reads.

Example usage: assuming that reads is a dictionary returned by read_data then:

```
get_all_overlaps(reads)
```

should return the following dictionary of dictionaries (but not necessarily with the same
ordering of the key-value pairs):

```
{'Read1': {'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read5': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 29},
'Read3': {'Read1': 0, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1, 'Read6': 1},
'Read2': {'Read1': 13, 'Read3': 1, 'Read5': 21, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 0},
'Read5': {'Read1': 39, 'Read3': 0, 'Read2': 1, 'Read4': 0, 'Read6': 14},
'Read4': {'Read1': 1, 'Read3': 1, 'Read2': 17, 'Read5': 2, 'Read6': 0},
'Read6': {'Read1': 0, 'Read3': 43, 'Read2': 0, 'Read5': 0, 'Read4': 1}}
```

Below is a dictionary, where the keys are the names of reads and the values are the associated
read sequences and my code to get_overlap

```
    read_map = {'Read1': 'GGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGC',
'Read3': 'GTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGTCGTGAACACATCAGT',
'Read2': 'CTTTACCCGGAAGAGCGGGACGCTGCCCTGCGCGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGG',
'Read5': 'CGATTCCAGGCTCCCCACGGGGTACCCATAACTTGACAGTAGATCTC',
'Read4': 'TGCGAGGGAAGTGAAGTATTTGACCCTTTACCCGGAAGAGCG',
'Read6': 'TGACAGTAGATCTCGTCCAGACCCCTAGCTGGTACGTCTTCAGTAGAAAATTGTTTTTTTCTTCCAAGAGGTCGGAGT'}


def get_overlap (left,right):
   max_overlap = min(len(left), len(right))
   for i in range(max_overlap):
      ovl = max_overlap - I
      if left[-ovl:] == right[:ovl]:
        return left[-ovl:]
return ''
```

The hints I got from the book:
I have to use the get_overlap function I just made to find the overlap between a
pair of reads. To generate all combinations of reads I need two for-loops. One looping
over reads in left positions and another (inside the first one) looping over reads in right
position. But we do not want the overlap of a read to itself, so there should
be an if-statement in the checking of the left and right reads are the same.

Even though we've got those hints, I have to admit that I'm still
confused and lost.Hope someone can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

This reads an awful lot like a homework question. You should really be having a go at solving it before asking for help - you would learn more that way.

Anyway, here is a solution:

```
def get_all_overlaps(read_map):
    result = {} # create an empty dictionary to put our results in
    for key1, item1 in read_map.items(): # loop over all items in the map
        result[key1] = {} # create an empty dictionary for this read
        for key2, item2 in read_map.items(): # loop over all the items a second time to compare
            if key1 == key2: # check if the reads are the same
                continue # they are the same, skip this comparison
            result[key1][key2] = len(get_overlap(item1,item2)) # compare overlaps and get the length
    return result # return the result
```